# 32-bit applications do not display some files in Windows 10

Tags: windows, 32bit-64bit, createfile

I'm developing a library for obtaining information from files in the portable executable format.

It is important for me that the library works in both 32-bit and 64-bit modes.

During testing, I used hard paths for example: L"C:\Windows\System32\ntoskrnl.exe" to display a list of exported functions.

In Windows 10, I discovered that in administrator mode, my 32-bit application returns error code 2 (ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) when trying to open an existing file, while the 64-bit application successfully opens this file.

In Windows 7 on another computer, both applications successfully open this file.

In addition, I discovered that many applications on Windows 10, in particular Total Commander, winhex, x32dbg, ollydbg, do not see many files in the System32 folder.

I can read them from disk by jumping around the file system, is there any easier way?

Comment: A 32-bit application trying to look into or access files in `%WINDIR%\System32` is automatically redirected to see the contents of `%WINDIR%\SysWOW64`... That said, as far as I'm aware, that has been the case since Windows XP (the first OS to have a 64-bit variant), so I'm not sure why you can see them in Windows 7.

Comment: I thought about this too because I once encountered a similar redirect in the registry.
I would like to add that when in the application, when I click on the “open” button, I can see the explorer and click on the properties of the systems32 folder then in the 32-bit application it shows that there are 8800 files, and in 64bit the properties show 14000 files.
on win7 there are also differences in the number of displayed files in this folder, it’s just that ntoskrnl.exe is present there.
maybe it really is a redirect.

Comment: Could it be possible that Windows 7 has a 32-bit ntoskrnl.exe in C:\Windows\SysWOW64, while Windows 10 no longer has it?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Mark Rotteveel the Windows on Windows 64 (WOW64) performs automatic redirection of certain file system (e.g. C:\Windows\System32, C:\Program Files) directories and registry keys (e.g. HKLM\Software, HKCU\Software) for 32-bit programs running on 64-bit systems.

The file system redirection can be turned off by calling [Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wow64apiset/nf-wow64apiset-wow64disablewow64fsredirection) and then re-enabled with [Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wow64apiset/nf-wow64apiset-wow64revertwow64fsredirection)

For the registry there is a flag (KEY_WOW64_32KEY) in the RegOpenKeyEx function to see the 32-bit view of the registry.